# How to join a sequence of tuples, each with its own sequence?

Tags: rust

I have a sequence of tuples where each tuple contains another sequences.
To better illustrate the problem, please have a look at the below snippet ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3333db77e492ce7fd42b6d1c1c6d47e)):

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = [
        (vec![1, 2, 3], vec!['a']), 
        (vec![4, 5, 6], vec!['b', 'c'])
    ];
    let res: (Vec<i32>, Vec<char>) = data...?

    // res = (vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], vec!['a', 'b', 'c']);

}
```

I would like to iterate `data` only once to create two `Vec`s. Each `Vec` is a concatenation of all the elements within a corresponding tuple's member.
`res` is a commented out expected result.

How this can be achieved in Rust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce).

```rust
let res: (Vec<i32>, Vec<char>) = data
    .into_iter()
    .reduce(|(mut acc1, mut acc2), (mut i1, mut i2)| {
        acc1.append(&mut i1);
        acc2.append(&mut i2);
        (acc1, acc2)
    })
    // An empty sequence will produce `(vec![], vec![])`
    .unwrap_or_default();
```

Comment: Or `fold`, which requires fewer type annotations and avoids the `unwrap`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5d35cec340ad275e0965c6788ada66b)

Comment: @Jmb that has the same amount of type annotations (the ones I put are not necessary) and will allocate slightly more often (although mine isn't perfectly optimal either)